# Can decoupling capacitors affect an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, decoupling

[image]I designed a PCB that has a 74HC14 to catch pulses and powered the PCB from the Arduino's pins (3.3V and gnd.) I placed a 0.1uf ceramic capacitor  between Vcc and gnd pin of the IC. I also added a 10uf capacitor directly on Vcc (3.3V) and gnd of the Arduino.

Is placement of 10uf wrong? The Arduino stops working after a few days. Does it affect the microprocessor? Where should the 10uf capacitor to be positioned, how many cm away from IC?

Comment: Adding an extra 10μF capacitor on the power rail of the Arduino shouldn't cause any problems. Most likely something else is going on, like a software bug that causes a crash very sporadically.

Comment: Since you don't tell anything about the circuit or software, the problem could be in the hardware design or software. Even if the problem is not in the design or software, the specific instance of hardware can have a broken component or bad solder joint. Or it might be powered from a flaky power supply. If you need more specific info what could cause this, you also need to provide more info, otherwise this is just generic guesswork.

Comment: I attached simple shematic of the circuit, the six pins of the IC used as same way.

Comment: Your LED should have a current limiting resistor. Otherwise it may overload the HC14 port and/or burn out.

Comment: I am just using 3mm red LED and no problem so far. Is there anyting to fix or add on circuit design ?